# How to scroll the textbox to appropriate position when virtual keyboard pops-up in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form

I am using J2ME, Lwuit and Blackberry api for developing my app.

My form contains textbox as well as toolbar. While touching the textbox, the virtual keyboard appears and then disappears. This is happening due to the toolbar. Even if I remove the toolbar, the textbox remains beneath the virtual keyboard instead of scrolling up. 
Issue is happening for the touch phones, for which we have to use touch screen.

I want the textbox to scroll up to the appropriate level to make it convenient for user.

Did anybody faced the same issue! Please share the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in LWUIT in that specific feature. It might have been fixed in [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Did you know that you need a different UI lib for Blackberry touch development? If you don't import this specific lib you can find foreign issues. You must import a lib called UI_RIM_Touch.jar, if you generate this project with the Resource editor, you can find this file in the root of your project. Try this.